# AngularJS Textbox not changed to valid after set as required using $setValidity("required",false)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have textbox, am setting as required field on button click event using below code in my JQuery file

```
>             document.getElementById("txtboxID").required = true;
>             $scope.txtboxID = '';
>             $scope.FormName.txtboxID.$setValidity("required", false);
```

Textbox HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : FormName.@txtboxID.$invalid  }">  
<input type="text" id="txtboxID" name="txtboxID" class="form-control" ng-model="txtboxID" >  
<p ng-show="FormName.txtboxID.$error.required" class="help-block col-xs-12 col-sm-reset inline">Text box is required</p>  
</div>
```

After button Click event -> Textbox required validation working fine.
[image]

But after I typed something in textBox class name

> 'ng-invalid-required ng-invalid'

is not changing. Please refer the below snap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) says, you need to use the `ng-required` directive for Angular to be able to properly work with the attribute. It will allow you to conditionally set a field's requirement based on a boolean `$scope` variable.

Example:

`<input type="text" id="txtboxID" name="txtboxID" class="form-control" ng-model="txtboxID" ng-required="txtboxRequired">`

`txtboxRequired` being a variable in your Angular controller's scope, toggled on and off at your discretion. I'd heavily suggest making sure the function that toggles this is a function in your `$scope` variable, and only call it with `ng-click` (or by something else in your controller).

In general, you shouldn't be trying to manipulate the DOM in an Angular app.

Comment: To answer your question, My requirement to set Textbox as required field only after the button click event. Otherwise that textbox should be non-required field. So I choose above way yo set required field. Basically I need to set Textbox field as Required only at runtime button click event.

Comment: @Developer_29 I found what was likely a better answer and edited mine. Check what I have now.

Comment: Great! Working fine. Thank you. Appreciate your help.